# AOAG and SQL Alias question

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server, 2016

A thread on here states that for SharePoint using AOAG, the recommendation is to use the listener and no alias.

That's fine but one of the things I do is I use two seperate SQL Aliases on a standard clustered setup. One alias for search databases (which can get big), another for everything.

This way I have granularity in moving just search databases, if required.

How could I do this with AOAG listeners and SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two AOAG groups on the same sql servers.User AG 1 for everything and AG2 for the search.

I think two groups also help u in performance.

Comment: Presumably then I need two listeners? If possible?

Comment: Yes you need two listeners and I have this thing in one of my deployment.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense. One more question:- In a SQL Cluster with named instances, what does the SQL alias use? The cluster network name (which shows up in the SQL Server properties), or  networkClusterName\instanceName (of node)?